# NextJs Export a named export for each HTTP method instead

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

I'm following a tutorial of NextJs Airbnb clone, he's using experimental and i'm using the latest version of nextjs, I don't understand how the routing works in NextJs especially for API calls. I tried to search on this and change even the routing path, but I think I still get an error.

It is working when I'm registering, but when I logged in, I get an error of

> error Detected default export in 'E:\Program\airbnb\app\api\auth[...nextauth]\route.ts'. Export a named export for each HTTP method instead.

This is my routing path:

[image]

inside my app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js

```
export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    providers: [
        GithubProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET as string
        }),
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ClIENT_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string
        }),
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: 'credentials',
            credentials: {
                email: {label: 'email', type: 'text'},
                password: {label: 'password', type: 'password'},
            },
            async authorize(credentials){
                if(!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password){
                    throw new Error('Invalid Credentials')
                }

                //Finding Email / User Account
                const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
                    where: {
                        email: credentials.email,
                    },
                });


                //Finding Password
                if(!user || !user?.hashedPassword){
                    throw new Error('Invalid Credentials')
                }

                const isCorrectPassword = await bcrypt.compare(
                    credentials.password,
                    user.hashedPassword
                );

                if(isCorrectPassword){
                    throw new Error('Invalide Credentials')
                }

                return user
            }
        })
    ],

    pages: {
        signIn: '/',
    },
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt'
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET
   
}

export default NextAuth
```

register/route.js

```
export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const body = await request.json();
  const { email, name, password } = body;

  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

  const user = await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      email,
      name,
      hashedPassword,
    },
  });

  return NextResponse.json(user);
}
```

And this is my LoginModal.ts

```
const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FieldValues> = (data) => {
    setIsLoading(true)
   
    signIn('credentials',{
      ...data,
      redirect: false,
    })
    .then((callback) => {
      setIsLoading(false)

      if(callback?.ok){
        toast.success('Logged In')
        router.refresh()
        loginModal.onClose()
      }

      if(callback?.error){
        toast.error(callback.error)
      }

    })
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You need a handler because you are using Route Handlers in NextJS 13. So, in your api/auth/[...nextauth], simply change `export default NextAuth` to:

```
const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)
export { handler as GET, handler as POST}
```

This is how you would use export in route handlers using next-auth. If you want to read more about it you can see it [here in their docs](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/initialization).